# Run TestNG groups sequentially and tests in each group in parallel

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, testng

I have several tests suites based on the functionality they test and I want to run them in parallel - to complete more quickly. It turned out that within one suite I need to put several tests that run against different environmental setting. I think I can do this by assigning tests to groups and then use the @BeforeGroups annotation to insert a method which set ups the environmental settings. However I don't know how to make the tests within each group to run in parallel and groups to wait for each other - otherwise there will be tests working in the wrong environment. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your dependencies of the groups in the xml.  Example [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml)

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting something more complicated. But this, though simple, does the job.